# How to add and use MessageQueues to ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, message-queue, msmq, using

I have a ASP.NET MVC project and I need to use Message Queues (MSMQ as I understand it) to send messages from the client to my server, but I can't seem to add `System.Messages` to a c# class. I get an error when trying to add the namespace:

[image]

I searched around and found that I don't have the system.messaging.dll (or system.messages.dll) in my project. This has to be possible, as [its even in the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue?view=netframework-4.8)

EDIT: I found another guy online [who is having the exact same problem.](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/240471-system-messaging) I followed the answer in that link, but the Refrence Manager dosen't seem to have a system.messaging or messages dll.

[image: not found]

How do I download the necessary dlls?

Comment: Did you try looking in the Browse node instead of COM within the Reference Manager?

Comment: @mason I just tried, but it says `No items found`

Comment: Do you *have* to use MSMQ? I haven't worked with it much, but my understanding is that it's very old and difficult to work with. Have you considered using the [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/) library, perhaps combined with RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus? By building on top of MassTransit, you can easily swap out transports and it has a lot more of the plumbing built into it to have a production ready app - and good documentation.

Comment: @mason I think I can use Azure Service Bus. Does it work well with message queues? How do I use it?

Comment: You'd have to create the bus connections in Azure (you can do so via the [web portal](https://portal.azure.com/)), then retrieve the shared key.  From there you plop it into the MassTransit configuration. Like I said, it's [well documented](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html). I suggest you give that a shot, follow the documentation. If you get stuck then perhaps a separate question explaining what you've tried and what's not working would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, @mason, I'll get to work setting it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @mason regrettably, I was trying to do something that isn't really done anymore. This question was outdated before I even asked it.